# Writing html in a string

Tags: java, html, escaping, stringbuilder

I'm trying a write a couple small lines of html in my java class that gets some data from another API. I get the data in a JSON string, and would then like to display some of it on a webpage.

To create the HTML, I try:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<leads.size();i++){
        sb.append("<p>Name: "+leads.get(i).getFirstName()+" "+leads.get(i).getLastName()+"</p>");
        sb.append("<p>Email: "+leads.get(i).getEmail()+"</p>");
        sb.append("<br />");
    }
    fullLeadData = sb.toString();
```

But what ends up being displayed is a literal interpretation of the html tags. Is there a way that I can create this string so that the tags will stay as tags and not the escaped characters?

The java class is a managed bean, so in the html I have:

```
    <body>
    <div id="display">
        #{PortalView.fullLeadData}
    </div>
</body>
```

Where fullLeadData is the string with the html.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to display this text?

Comment: updated my post, displaying on that webpage

Comment: concatenating strings inside of the append method is not a very good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you're using JSF. Try this:

```
<div id="display">
    <h:outputText value="#{PortalView.fullLeadData}" escape="false"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to replace the escape sequences. The common ones being

```
‘&’ (ampersand)  ‘&amp;‘
‘"’ (double quote)  ‘&quot;‘
”’ (single quote)  ‘&#039;‘
‘<’ (less than)  ‘&lt;‘
‘>’ (greater than)  ‘&gt;‘
```