# JSF Bean return HTML to DataTable

Tags: html, jsf, datatable

This is my `dataTable` and I need my bean property `status` is like this:

`<span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>` but it is printing the text, not compiling the `html` and `dataTable` or `column` doesn't have the `espace` option. Is there a way to solve this?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{pedidoController.orderList}" var="order"
                                 styleClass="table table-striped">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                            #{order.orderNo}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Cliente</f:facet>
                            #{order.client}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
                            #{order.date}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                            #{order.status}
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use h:outputText to display the data and not the implicit JSF output. Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402900/writing-html-in-a-string/10403035#10403035) and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks, just changed my bean lines to: `<h:outputText value="#{order.date}" escape="false"/>`